# Ionic Capacitor Push Notification Invalid Platform token on SNS

Tags: ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, capacitor

I've successfully setup Push Notifications for both iOS and Android via SNS.

However, when I deployed it to a Production app, SNS returns "Platform token associated with the endpoint is not valid" when sending to APNS tokens/endpoints.

I'm creating the platform application endpoint via the Key method (.p8), and I use the Capacitor Push plugin to register device tokens.

Did I miss anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does work correctly, there was a typo on my configuration with APNS on SNS. If you encounter this, just double check the fields required by SNS, in my case bundleID was wrong.